# Having problems getting the metadata for Spotify songs

Tags: android, android-intent, filter, spotify

I am working on an app that needs to know what music the user is listening to.
For the default music player, I can listen for the `com.android.music.metachanged` broadcast to know which songs are being played.

I found the option in the settings of the Spotify app to allow Device Broadcast Status.   However, even if I turn on this option, I do not get any music information when songs are played in Spotify from either the `com.android.music.metachanged` or the `com.spotify.mobile.android.metadatachanged` intent filters.

This worked before using the `com.spotify.mobile.android.metadatachanged`, but recently has stopped working.

Am I using the wrong intent filter or is there a different problem?

Comment: Are you using the `Metadata API` (Deprecated) ?? or the new `Web API`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having just fixed this myself, I suspect you'll find it's due to the change in the package name - Spotify recently changed the app due to a security flaw, and so all the intents are now different.

Replace **com.spotify.mobile.android** with **com.spotify.music** in your intents and you should be good to go.